# wp_pagenavi in Custom Blog Archive

Tags: php, wordpress

I already read several answer in SE network and WP forum and several log. but I am still in the dark.
At first, I have to say, my consequence is different.

- I created a Page Template `Blog` (blog.php) and added a wp_query on that page to show normal blog posts in that post because my homepage is a static homepage.
- Then I simply created a blank page named Blog with permalink /blog
- Next, I added wppagenavi on that ge after `elsewhile`
- It didn't work so I read couple of SOF answer and added 
  `<?php wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $the_query ) ); ?>`.
- It shows page navigation but not working. I clicked 2,3,4... button and it return same page though url changes to `/blog/page/2`

So, how to make page navi work?
My snippet

```
 <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=8' ); ?>

    <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
<div class="content-box bg-wrap"><?php 
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
<div class="img"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<?php
    the_post_thumbnail( 'blog_thumb' );
?>
</a></div>
<?php
}
?>
<div class="post-info p20px">
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<div class="post-meta"><span class="theauthor"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <?php echo get_the_author(); ?></span> <span class="thetime"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <?php the_date(); ?></span> <span class="thecategory"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i><?php the_category(', '); ?></span> <span class="thecomments"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i><?php echo $write_comments; ?></span> </div>
<br/>
<?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,600); ?> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read this post &raquo;</a>
</div>
</div>
    <?php endwhile;?>
    <?php wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $the_query ) ); ?>
```

Do not bother other functions and variables or html. I just need to make pagenavi work.
I got pagenavi code from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9576/wp-pagenavi-with-custom-wp-query)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and the solution as well.
I have to add `'&paged='.$paged` on `$wp_query()` and it enables navigation on that scenario. 
So, the first line

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=8' ); ?>
```

have to be replaced with

```
 <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=8' . '&paged='.$paged); ?>
```

That's all.
See a live preview (the project I applied this): [Here](http://bdalbum.com/blog)